# The full contents of the bind-variable are not displayed in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

I wrote a big query in bind-variable. I want to print it in SQL Plus, but the text doesn't show, only small part of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The length of a CLOB output is limited.
You can increase the limit with `set long n`, example:

```
set long 50000
```